# MDX Measure for Whole Previous Month (or previous month average day value)

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, ssas, mdx, dimension

I have a fairly standard Date dimension with Fiscal Hierarchy

```
FiscalYear -> FiscalQuarter -> FiscalMonth -> FiscalWeek -> Date
```

I'm trying to define an MDX expression to find the month member from any point in the cube. In other words, whatever the `CurrentMember` is in the hierarchy (from fiscal month down to a single date), I want to return the month attribute.

What I'm  trying to do is create a MonthToDate (MTD) previous period comparison KPI, where let's say we are 15 days into the current Fiscal month. I calculate the MTD for the current month (that's working) using:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[FY MTD Revenue Amount] AS
    Aggregate(
        PeriodsToDate([Date].[Fiscal].[Month], [Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember)
        , [Measures].[Revenue Amount]
    )
```

and I want to compare this with the (whole previous fiscal year's month amount / Number of days in previous year's fiscal month) * 15

I can calculate the previous year's Month-to-Date MTD using:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[FY MTD Revenue Amount Year Ago] AS
    Aggregate
    (
         PeriodsToDate([Date].[Fiscal].[Month], ParallelPeriod([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year], 1, [Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember))
        ,[Measures].[Revenue Amount]
    )
```

but what I really want is the "average day value for previous years month".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Solved it. I was thinking about it in the wrong way (as is often the case with MDX!).

Created a tuple using `Ancestor`. This works at the Day, Week and Month levels. I will need to use a `SCOPE` statement to control where it is applicable:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[FY Month Revenue Amount Year Ago] AS
(
    Ancestor(ParallelPeriod([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year], 1, [Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember),
             [Date].[Fiscal].[Month])
     ,[Measures].[Revenue Amount]
)
```

It finds the member in the previous fiscal year at the same relative position to the CurrentMember, then gets the ancestor of that member in the Fiscal Month hierarchy.